# New tab added to existing admin menu not displayed (plus a bit more!)

Tags: 7

In my custom module I have an admin menu opton with 2 tabs and it worked fine for times. Then I now added a 3rd tab.

But this 3rd tab didn't appear (although obviously I'd cleared the cache).

After checking all I could think to (including the presence of the right `page arguments` function), I tried to "shake" it a bit, hoping to observe something meaningful:

1. First I dropped my new 3rd tab to check that nothing changed: ok, 2 tabs.
2. Then I intentionally introduced a typo in the 2nd tab's `page arguments` and cleared the cache again: quite surprisingly I got the 2 first tabs still showing!
3. So having kinda blurred impression that clearing the cache seemed to have no effect, I dropped the 2nd tab too: this time it resulted as expected, with only the 1st tab's page shown (without physically displaying any tab).
4. Then I restored the 2nd tab, so going back to exactly the same as before my first attempt: but it kept showing only 1st item's page!
   And the same after also restoring the 3rd tab.

Here is the code:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  return array(
    'admin/config/regional/mymodule' => array(
      'title'            => 'mymodule',
      'description'      => 'mymodule configuration',
      'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments'   => array('mymodule_rendering_form'),
      'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
      'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      'file'             => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    ),
    'admin/config/regional/mymodule/rendering' => array(
      'title'            => 'Rendering',
      'description'      => 'Configure how mymodule must render',
      'type'             => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
      'file'             => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    ),
    'admin/config/regional/mymodule/tokens' => array(
      'tab_parent'       => 'admin/config/regional/mymodule',
      'title'            => 'Tokens',
      'description'      => 'Choose which tokens mymodule must clone',
      'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments'   => array('mymodule_tokens_form'),
      'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
      'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'file'             => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    ),
    // Above is the initial part, which worked fine.
    //
    // Below is the new tab I just added.
    'admin/config/regional/mymodule/default' => array(
      'tab_parent'       => 'admin/config/regional/mymodule',
      'title'            => 'Default values',
      'description'      => 'Reset some or all of the configuration options back to default values',
      'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments'   => array('mymodule_default_form'),
      'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
      'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'file'             => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    ),
  );
```

I hope I'm merely missing something obvious...

Comment: Hi, cFreed. What does the code for your third tab look like? Since 'page arguments' can be inherited I'm wondering if your deliberate typo caused Drupal to look look for it in your parent? Interesting. By the way, you don't need to specify 'tab_parent' here because it defaults to the same path without the last component.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I should have posted my own "answer" to inform that, inexplicably, all worked fine again two days later (including the third tab), without any change! So it will remain mysterious... Regarding `tab_parent` I agree that it is theorically useless, but it comes from another issue I had previously: it appeared to be the only way I could find to make the `admin_menu` to work properly (without it, I got all those tabs displayed as options at the same level!).

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working. :)